# i am try to create a stopwatch/timer with Xcode 4.2 but this error comes up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

i am copying this person of youtube but i think he has Xcode 3 or something can you help me 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jmTQi98vec&feature=related
this is the guy I'm trying to copy and this is where I'm up to:

> #import
>
> ```
>  @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
>
>
>
>        IBOutlet UILabel *time;
>
>        NSTimer *myticker;
>
>     }
>
> @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
>
>
> -(IBAction)start;
>
> -(IBAction)stop;                expected identifier or '('  
> -(IBAction)reset;
>
> -(void)showActivity;
> ```
>
> @end

can you help ???????

Comment: all it says is expected identifier or '('

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty #import statement at the top. Is that on purpose?

Comment: no don't worry about the import its there just not in the above window

Answer (score 0):

Only watched the vid for a minute but he's making the timer inside his main view controller and yours is in the delegate but aside from that your import statement is empty. At the top of the Delegate it should be :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```